# Cannot connect to Hadoop in Docker from Apache Nifi

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-nifi

I'm attempting to run the following Apache Nifi flow and put data into HDFS from Kafka:

[image]

I'm running [Confluent Kafka](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/master/examples/cp-all-in-one) and my Hadoop instance is the Cloudera quickstart.

**Cloudera Quickstart**

```
docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180 -p 80:80 -p 50070:50070 -p 8020:8020 -p 50010:50010 -p 50020:50020 -p 50075:50075 -p 50475:50475 -p 50090:50090 -p 50495:50495 -v $(pwd):/home/cloudera -w /home/cloudera cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

**Confluent Kafka**
https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/master/examples/cp-all-in-one

I'm receiving the following error when Nifi attempts to put data into HDFS. Nifi is able to connect to HDFS successfully (my config files are below for reference nonetheless).

Based on my initial research it seems that the namenode is unable to communicate with the datanode in HDFS but my addresses in hdfs-site.xml seem correct. I also have my ports exposed on my machine so that Nifi can communicate with Hadoop without using docker networking.

```
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: IOException thrown from PutHDFS[id=07704347-0165-1000-b8f7-b53809532c9a]: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /topics/users/.10180050823815 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2234)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2179)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS$1.run(PutHDFS.java:299)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1942)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.hadoop.PutHDFS.onTrigger(PutHDFS.java:229)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: File /topics/users/.10180050823815 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1595)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy151.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:496)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1668)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:716)
```

I have setup my HDFS instance with the following configuration files:

**core-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.0.1.28:8020</value>
  </property>

  <!-- OOZIE proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- HTTPFS proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Llama proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Hue proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <!-- Immediately exit safemode as soon as one DataNode checks in. 
       On a multi-node cluster, these configurations must be removed.  -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.safemode.extension</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.permissions</name>
     <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.safemode.min.datanodes</name>
     <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/name</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.checkpoint.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/namesecondary</value>
  </property>
  <property>
     <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/${user.name}/dfs/data</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:8022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.https.address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50470</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50070</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50010</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50075</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50475</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50090</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.https-address</name>
    <value>10.0.1.28:50495</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Impala configuration -->
  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.hdfs-blocks-metadata.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.file-block-storage-locations.timeout.millis</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.domain.socket.path</name>
    <value>/var/run/hadoop-hdfs/dn._PORT</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT: Updated docker-compose.yml file**

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: ${DOCKER_KAFKA_HOST}
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    volumes:
      - mi2:/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.0.0-beta30.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: /usr/share/java
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  control-center:
    #image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.0.0-beta30
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:5.0.0-beta1-2
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksql-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      #CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_URL: "http://ksql-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_ENDPOINT: "http://ksql-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021

  ksql-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: ksql-server
    container_name: ksql-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_LOG4J_OPTS: "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksql/log4j-rolling.properties"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:9092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksql-server
      KSQL_APPLICATION_ID: "cp-all-in-one"
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"

  ksql-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksql-cli:5.0.0-beta30
    container_name: ksql-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksql-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksql-examples:5.0.0-beta30
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    volumes:
      - mi2:/usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:9092 1 20 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 20 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       cp /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.0.0-beta30.jar /usr/share/java/ksql-examples/monitoring-interceptors-5.0.0-beta30.jar && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_LOG4J_OPTS: "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/ksql/log4j-rolling.properties"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:latest
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:9092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'

  cloudera:
      image: cloudera/quickstart
      container_name: cloudera
      privileged: true
      tty: true
      command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
      ports:
        - 80:80
        - 7180:7180
        - 8020:8020
        - 8888:8888
        - 50070:50070
        - 50010:50010
        - 50020:50020
        - 50075:50075
        - 50475:50475
        - 50090:50090
        - 50495:50495
      volumes: 
        - ./:/home/cloudera
      working_dir: /home/cloudera

  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config

volumes:
    mi2: {}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using Confluent's HDFS Kafka Connector?

Comment: @cricket_007 I want to standardize all my data routing and flow through NiFi rather than having to manage connectors. I plan on adding other data sources later that will store data in HDFS.

Comment: Your initial search is correct. Name node is unable to communicate with datanode. So it may be some networking issue or configuration issue. Now check the firewall issue or mention the 4 configuration files in it core-site.xml,yarn-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,hdfs-site.xml . Before doing that ensure namenode can communicate with data node from that namenode machine itself.

Comment: Fair enough. Although, you could use NiFi to put those external sources into Kafka, rather than only consuming from it with NiFi. I find that connect scales better than NiFi, personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your NiFi Container is on the same Docker network, you shouldn't be using a hard-coded IP addresses.

My suggestion would be to edit the Confluent Compose file (or make a separate compose file) and take your `docker run command` and reshape it into Compose form

For example

```
cloudera-cdh:
  image: cloudera/quickstart 
  command: /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
  ports:
    - ...
  volumes: 
    - $PWD:/home/cloudera
```

Do the same with a NiFi container

And then, your `hdfs-site.xml` file should be able to reach `hdfs://cloudera-cdh:50070` over the Docker network via the service names.

---

Note: You can accomplish a similar task using `docker network create [name]`, and passing `--network [name]` via `docker run`

---

FWIW, there are better Hadoop containers that don't include the full CDH stack if you only want HDFS. (`bde2020` and `uhopper` images)

Comment: By fixing my docker-compose file as you mentioned I managed to get Nifi to write to HDFS. Unfortunately my cloudera container keeps exiting with code 0. I think it may be because of resource constraints on my machine (MBP i7 4 cores , 16gb ram). I don't have any errors on Nifi and when I view the logs for Cloudera the last two lines look like

`cloudera           | Started Impala Server (impalad):[  OK  ]
cloudera exited with code 0
`

Comment: Also regarding Nifi vs Kafka - I'm going to try using the connector and see which works better. Since in my architecture Kafka is the main stream processing engine your point about using Nifi to load data into Kafka is valid. I initially had gotten Kafka -> HDFS working that way but have not tried it with Dockerized Kafka & HDFS.

Comment: Fixed my own problem with cloudera shutting down with tty:true.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the `Directory` property with the path like `/path/to/your/files` for `PutHDFS`, you may want to change that into a complete one, meaning with the NameNode hostname/IP and port like `hdfs://namenode-host:port/path/to/your/files`